# Column Mean for rows with unique values

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, mean

how can I compute the mean R, R1, R2, R3 values from the rows sharing the same lon,lat field? I'm sure this questions exists multiple times but I could not easily find it.

```
   lon       lat      length    depth   R      R1     R2     R3
1 147.5348 -35.32395  13709     1       0.67   0.80   0.84   0.83
2 147.5348 -35.32395  13709     2       0.47   0.48   0.56   0.54
3 147.5348 -35.32395  13709     3       0.43   0.29   0.36   0.34
4 147.4290 -35.27202  12652     1       0.46   0.61   0.60   0.58
5 147.4290 -35.27202  12652     2       0.73   0.96   0.95   0.95
6 147.4290 -35.27202  12652     3       0.77   0.92   0.92   0.91
```

Comment: try `aggregate(R ~ lon, data = df, FUN = mean)` put all in a apply call. `apply(df[,4:8], 2, function(x){aggregate(x ~ lon, data = df, FUN = mean)})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [split-apply-combine strategy](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v040i01/v40i01.pdf), where you're splitting by BOTH lon and lat, applying `mean` to each group, then recombining into a single data frame.

I'd recommend using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
   group_by(lon, lat) %>%
   summarize(
       mean_r = mean(R)
     , mean_r1 = mean(R1)
     , mean_r2 = mean(R2)
     , mean_r3 = mean(R3)
  )
```

Comment: Or, briefer: `mydata %>% group_by(lon, lat) %>% summarise_at(vars(contains("R")), mean)`.